# How to port React.createClass to ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I used to say

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {  
        var stocks = {};
    ...

feed.onChange(function(stock) {            
            stocks[stock.symbol] = stock;
            this.setState({stocks: stocks, bid: stock, ask: stock, last: stock, type: stock, undsymbol: stock});
        }.bind(this));

        return {
            stocks: stocks
        };
    },  
    componentDidMount() {              
        var props = this.props;
    },
    ...

},
```

But there is no `getInitialState` in ES6. But where to put the statement in the `constructor`:

```
return {
                stocks: stocks
       };
```

It complains that there is no `render` function.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    // Can't do this here
    //  return {
    //       stocks: stocks
    //  };
}
```

When I execute `this.state.stocks[stock.symbol]` I get

```
app.js:555 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'JNJ' of undefined
    at n.feed.onChange (<anonymous>:555:45)


componentDidMount() {              
        //var props = this.props;

         feed.onChange((stock) => {            
            this.state.stocks[stock.symbol] =
```

**Confused as to how (where to put)** `return {stocks:stocks}`

Comment: [State and Lifecycle: Adding Local State to a Class](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) and [React Without ES6: Setting the Initial State](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state)

Answer (score 0):

You simply set the `state` property of the component explicitly:

```
this.state = {
    stocks: stocks
};
```

in the constructor.

Comment: stocks is undefined

Comment: @Ivan not sure how it's relevant. If you have not defined it - it surely is undefined.